# Multiple instance of same class get different instanceof

Tags: javascript, class, npm, webpack

I have a private package that export a class named `Table`, I have an other package that use this class and I have my web application that use this class too. 
Inside my second package I have a test like this

```
if (!(table instanceof Table)) {
   throw new TypeError(table + ' is not an instance of Table');
}
```

I've put a breakpoint here and when I log `table` it's a `Table` so the test shouldn't be false but when I look closer to the compiled code I have :

```
if (!(table instanceof _mypackage2.Table)) {
   throw new TypeError(table + ' is not an instance of Table');
}
```

It looks like I have different instance of my class `Table` and the instance from the second package is not the same as the first one. I thought that it's a package version issue but when I run `npm list mypackage` here is what I have :

```
├── @pck/mypackage@2.7.2 
└─┬ @pck/otherpackage@2.7.3
  ├── @pck/mypackage@2.7.2
```

The version of the package is the same, how can I do to check for the instance or to have the same instance between the package. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

just add to `package.json`

`resolutions` object

```
{
  "resolutions": {
    "mypackage": "2.7.2"
  }
}
```

https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/package-json/#toc-resolutions

Comment: This is for `yarn` I'm using `npm`, there is a package for it but it uses the `package-lock.json` and I'm using `npm-shrinkwrap.json` file

Comment: it uses package-lock.json but I use npm-shrinkwrap.json